# What is the magento way to hide an html element in a phtml until the page is loaded in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to hide the customer register form until the page is loaded, I know I can use jQuery or plain javascript, but I'd like to do it using Magento2 own resources, the markup I'm using right now:

```
<div id="register-form">
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="/customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I've found to do it is adding those attributes to the container div:

```
<div id="register-form" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true">
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="/customer/account/createpost/" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
</div>
```